# Verilog code for this question

Tags: verilog, flipflop, shift-register, sequential-logic

The question in my textbook was:

> Design and implement a Serial 2’s Complementer with a Shift Register and
> a flip–flop. The binary number is shifted out from one side and it’s
> 2’s complement shifted into the other side of the shift register.

I got the solution but I was curious to know the Verilog implementation of it. How do I do that?
[image: circuit diagram]

This is the solution.

EDIT: my actual circuit diagram.
[image: My circuit diagram]

Comment: Why is your output fed back to the input?

Comment: Where did you get your solution from?

Comment: @ShashankVM because they have asked to

Comment: @ShashankVM i did that because i dont have a good quality cam to take the pic of my circuit.

Comment: edaplayground.com is a good  option for designing and simulating Verilog options for free. Try it and show your efforts, if you get stuck, then come back with specific questions. This question does not fit this site because this site is not a free design house nor is it a homework answering service. It is unlikely that you will get the full Verilog code of what you want on this site.

Comment: @ShashankVM the question doesnt need the verilog code,I submitted the circuit and it sufficed.This was pure person interest question to see the verilog code.

Comment: @ShashankVM the output is fed back into the input because the question says the binary number is shifted into the input

Comment: If the output is fed back to the input, it does not make any sense to write the Verilog code for this, or to design an IC for this. - This is my opinion

Comment: @ShashankVM I agree with your opinion.There is no way to feed the input to the above question.

Comment: If you feedback, what happens is that: Suppose I load 1010 initially, I will get 0110 serially, which is fed back to the input 
Then I get 1010 serially at output, which is fed back again. It goes 1010, 0110, 1010, 0110 .... Ah maybe this is the intention.

Answer (score 2):

ESE doesn't promote free coding service, we can only guide. You already have the circuit with you. So look at it and try to code structurally for example -

1. Design a simple shift register which is loadable with a parallel binary data (tons of references in google).
2. Design a D flip-flop module with reset (basics).
3. Instantiate and integrate both of them in a top module.
4. Just map the signals between your shift register and flip-flop as shown in the figure, imagine them as wires and how you would connect these two hardwares on a breadboard.

Otherwise, understand the functionality and code the complete circuit in behaviour model. You can do design this in Verilog in many ways.

Comment: It would be the binary number whose 2's compliment is serially output if this is implemented using a PISO shift register.

Comment: The circuit shows serial output has to be fed back to the input. So tell me what you will do if I want to find the 2's compliment of  say no. "1010"? How will you feed it to the shift register in this scenario?

Comment: Otherwise, the circuit given by @Savannah has to be wrong. Feed input serially. Take the 2's compliment out serially. No feed back as shown in her circuit.

Comment: Yes, I also feel the circuit is wrong. Apparently the OP copied it from here, on page 3. https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~msachdev/ECE223/Assignment7_solution_3rd_edition.pdf

Comment: @ShashankVM I have posted the circuit diagram I had initially got.

Comment: @ShashankVM I copied it because I didnt want to post the bad quality picture.As you can see I have posted my solution.

Comment: Good. Now try to code yourself.

Comment: @MituRaj Thanks for the guidelines.I will try to code and post my code here.